# Jhipster Ionic Error while creating app : getJhipsterAppConfig is not a function

Tags: java, angular, ionic-framework, npm, jhipster

I'm trying to start a new Jhipster Ionic but i'm stuck with this error :

```
$yo jhipster-ionic
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: this.getJhipsterAppConfig is not a function
    at module.exports.readConfig (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster-ionic\generators\app\index.js:63:47)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster-ionic\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\index.js:424:27)
    at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster-ionic\node_modules\run-async\index.js:25:25
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster-ionic\node_modules\run-async\index.js:24:19
    at self.env.runLoop.add.completed (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster-ionic\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\index.js:425:13)
    at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
```

Here is my npm versions :

```
+ yo@2.0.6
+ generator-jhipster-ionic@3.3.0
+ ionic@4.12.0
+-- generator-jhipster@6.0.1
`-- generator-jhipster-ionic@3.3.0
  `-- generator-jhipster@6.0.1
```

Can someone provide some help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently it's an known error and the jhipster-ionic team is currently working on it.

I have found a temporary solution :

In the file : C:...\YourPersonalDirectory\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster-ionic\generators\app\index.js

Replace :

```
this.jhipsterAppConfig = this.getJhipsterAppConfig();
```

By

```
this.jhipsterAppConfig = this.getAllJhipsterConfig();
```