# Jhipster entity audit

Tags: entity, jhipster, audit

I have installed the audit entity component: https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/marketplace/#/details/generator-jhipster-entity-audit
But when I run the jhipster-entity-audit command it tells me not recognized command. I am under windows and I use CMD

Comment: You mean the `yo jhipster-entity-audit` command as explained in module's README, right? Just checking as you omitted *yo* in your question.

Comment: The `TypeError: this.getJhipsterAppConfig is not a function` error is a known issue that impacts other modules as well, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56191820/jhipster-ionic-error-while-creating-app-getjhipsterappconfig-is-not-a-function for a workaround, and please report the issue to the module's author at https://github.com/hipster-labs/generator-jhipster-entity-audit/issues

Answer (score 0):

the current version of the module doesn't work with the latest JHipster version.

However, you can use the latest master version of the module in your project:

`npm install -g git+https://github.com/hipster-labs/generator-jhipster-entity-audit.git`

then it should work.

Comment: I-m using jhipster generator version 6.5.1, but soing this does not work either: `Welcome to the JHipster Entity Audit Generator! v3.1.1

Error jhipster-entity-audit

ERROR!  I support only JHipster versions greater than >=5.0.0...
            If you want to use Entity Audit with an older JHipster version, download a previous version that supports the required JHipster version.`

Comment: I am using jhipster version 6.4.1 and it's working.

Comment: hey @RaptoX is that an official module of jhipster to audit entities on jhipster app ?

Comment: it's a third party module for Jhipster

Comment: @RaptoX please can you provide me a tutorial step by step to apply this module to audit all action on my entities